# ClassNotFound using model from Mahout

Tags: java, maven, mahout, mahout-recommender

Hello guys i have this error after following the documentation and tutorial as i'm attempting to use mahout. It complains about DataModel even though it's included in the pom.xml. Could someone please tell me what i did wrong:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/model/DataModel
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2688)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2937)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1771)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.model.DataModel
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 6 more
```

Below is my code:

```
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.common.TasteException;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.eval.RecommenderBuilder;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.eval.RecommenderEvaluator;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.eval.AverageAbsoluteDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file.FileDataModel;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.neighborhood.ThresholdUserNeighborhood;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.recommender.GenericUserBasedRecommender;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.similarity.PearsonCorrelationSimilarity;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.model.DataModel;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.neighborhood.UserNeighborhood;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.recommender.*;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.similarity.UserSimilarity;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class UserBasedRecommendation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            DataModel dataModel = new FileDataModel(new File("path to my file"));
            UserSimilarity similarity = new PearsonCorrelationSimilarity(dataModel);
            UserNeighborhood neighborhood = new ThresholdUserNeighborhood(0.1, similarity, dataModel);
            UserBasedRecommender recommender = new GenericUserBasedRecommender(dataModel, neighborhood, similarity);
            List<RecommendedItem> recommendations = recommender.recommend(2, 3);
            for (RecommendedItem recommendation : recommendations) {
                System.out.println(recommendation);
            }

            //evaluation
            RecommenderEvaluator recommenderEvaluator = new AverageAbsoluteDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator();
            RecommenderBuilder recommenderBuilder = new MyRecommenderBuilder();
            double result = recommenderEvaluator.evaluate(recommenderBuilder, null, dataModel, 0.9, 1.0);
            System.out.println(result);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("There was an error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static class MyRecommenderBuilder implements RecommenderBuilder {

        public Recommender buildRecommender(DataModel dataModel) throws TasteException {
            UserSimilarity similarity = new PearsonCorrelationSimilarity(dataModel);
            UserNeighborhood neighborhood = new ThresholdUserNeighborhood(0.1, similarity, dataModel);
            return new GenericUserBasedRecommender(dataModel, neighborhood, similarity);
        }
    }
}
```

my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>edu.sjsu.cmpe239</groupId>
    <artifactId>project1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Mahout</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
            <artifactId>mahout-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.9</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```